# Error on site after EF5 code-first Azure deployment

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a MVC4 EF5 code-first application on Azure. After publishing I get this error on the site:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

I guess thats because the tables aren't being created in the database?

My connectionstring:

```
Data Source=tcp:6666666.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=eatart_db;User Id=kasperskov@6666666;Password=yourmother
```

I have automatic migrations enabled in the config and I am executing it on deployment:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<EatArt.Models.EatArtDb>
{
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }
}
```

In my Application_Start (global.asax):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EatArtDb>());
```

ALSO. This notification pops op on my azure portal:

> The server encountered an error while retrieving metrics. Retry the
>   operation.

What am I missing here? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: are you using sql azure or is your database hosted someplace else?  Is this the first time you published to azure?  or have you been doing this a while and it just stopped working?

Comment: @BenTidman - Yes sql azure. And yes I had it working.

Comment: @BenTidman - I might have re-created the website and database at some point. But non the less I would have made the same deployment procedures. I have this feeling that the connectionstring have to contain something specific the first time you deploy in order for the tables to be created, and then removed again after first run. Can that be right?

Comment: Hmm... all long shots but... Not sure if you need this for automatic migrations but for code first I had to add a firewall exception for for computers IP so that I could connect to it and run update database.  Are you able to connect to database via ssms?  Also if you re-created your sql azure server it may have a different connection string now.

Comment: Ill try and run Update-Database migration command through VS if that is what you mean. If that doesnt work im forced to create a new project and copy the code from the old project and try deploy again.

Comment: @BenTidman - It worked. I ran the Update-Database command from VS with a connection to my azure database, instead of depending on the automatic migration in web deploy. Add it as an answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Tidman suggested, I ran the Update-Database command in the package manager console onto the Azure database. That triggered the creation of the tables and I was able to deploy a view the page right away.

Ps. Had to add `Trusted_Connection=false` and `encrypt=true` to the connection string of course..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with EF. My approach was to move away from using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` and switch to using migrations. Here's a useful article on [code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Change your `DropCreate` line to this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EatArtDb, Configuration>());
```

You've enabled automatic migrations already but aren't using them in the initializer.

Comment: Throughs error: > System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

Comment: And i've had it working before and im pretty sure I had the DropCreate. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the name of your connection string? Does it match the name of your DbContext? It needs to match up in the Azure Portal

Comment: Well. I dont get to choose a name for my connection string. The web deploy thingo does that for me with the publish profile